# Need help making active state On Click for state labels on jQuery Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I'm working on an interactive map using the New Signature US map plugin. You can see my code here: http://codepen.io/ann_kwilinski/pen/EKdGYW

I'm also going to preface this with I am a beginner with javascript.

I need to add an active state to my state labels and I am really stuck on how to write that. The plugin has the hover state options but not active state.

```
'labelTextHoverStyles': {
            fill: '#000000'
        },
```

If any one can point me in a direction on how to do that it would be much appreciated.

**Update**

I need help binding the the stateSpecificLabelStyles to the click event I already have:

```
'click' : function(event, data) {
 $('#clicked-state')
 .text('Breathe Better Network partners in '+ data.name)
 .stop()
 .animate({backgroundColor: '#ddd'}, 1000);

// Populate List in Panel
                //var stateSelected = data.name;
                var stateContent = $('#'+data.name+'-li').html();
                // alert(stateContent);
                $("#state-list-response").html(stateContent);

                //Open Panel List
                $(".state-list-overlay").slideDown( "fast", function() {
                    $(".state-list-panel").slideDown( "fast", function() {
                        $(".state-list").fadeIn();
                  });
              });

                $("#map > svg > path").each(function(i){
                    $(this).css('fill', '');
                });
                $('#' + data.name).css('fill', '#26aedf');
                },


    });
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use `stateSpecificStyles` property of [JQuery U.S Map](https://newsignature.github.io/us-map/#usage-style-options):

```
$('#map').usmap({
  stateSpecificStyles: {
    'MD': {fill: 'yellow'},
    'VA': {fill: 'teal'}
  } 
});
```

> As 'MD' and 'VA' are your state codes in the MAP.

**Update:** And yes, you can also bind your own Click event like:

```
    click: function(event, data) {

      // Output the abbreviation of the state name to the browser's console. Press f12 in your browser to see this result.
      console.log(data.name);

      // And when you have the state abbreviation, you can use the above example like this:
      stateSpecificStyles: {
        data.name: {fill: 'black'}
      }

    }
```

Comment: okay yes, I see I can bind stateSpecificStyles with an event, but is there a way to make all the state labelTextStyles change to black on click like how it has the map change to a color on click without having to write out all 50 state abbreviations?

Comment: Check my update and if it helped you don't forget to mark as correct or up-voting at least :)